# How does the browser handle TCP out of band data?

Tags: browser, tcp, out-of-band

I am interested in understanding whether browsers can handle TCP OOB data sent to them from a server? For instance, I request a web page (from my web server) using firefox browser, and I inject some OOB data in the middle of the response stream from the web server. It seems that if the OOB data is sent after an entire object (e.g. image, stylesheet, javascript) is returned, then the browser does not face any trouble in reading and loading that object. However, if the OOB data is sent in the middle of an object's byte stream, then the browser may fail to load that object. I am not sure if the browser does not manage to receive the remaining of the object after the OOB data or it just fails to load the object.

Apart from looking at the source code of a browser, is there any other reference to understand this aspect of the browser behaviour?

Thanks and regards